# HDIV issue while redirecting in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, hdiv

I have inherited some Java Spring MVC code that does internal redirects in the Controller on a form submission

Ex:

Form is submitted to

```
/login_submit       (POST request)
```

On success, it is redirected inside controller :-

```
.....
return "redirect:"+"/user/home"
```

However, since it is inside code and not using `<c:redirect>` or `<c:url>` tags, HDIV fails this form submission with

> INVALID_ACTION error

Please help on understanding and resolving this preferably without changing the legacy code too much

Many thanks in advance for your prompt reply!!!

Comment: please add the error log and code samples

Comment: What version of HDIV and Spring MVC are you using? It should work because HDIV intercepts that "redirect:". It seems that you have a problem with the request's action. Please, give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve it,

1) To skip the validation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHdivWebSecurity
public class HdivSecurityConfig extends HdivWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addExclusions(ExclusionRegistry registry) {
        registry.addUrlExclusions("/user/home");
    }
}
```

2) URL can be generated with HDIV's processor as can be seen below,

```
 LinkUrlProcessor urlProcessor = HDIVUtil.getLinkUrlProcessor(servletContext);
 String processUrl = urlProcessor.processUrl(request, "/user/home");
 return "redirect:"+processUrl;
```

I hope this should resolve the issue.

Comment: 1) It is not recommended to do this due to you are skipping the validation of that URL. 2) It is not necessary because HDIV intercepts that redirect.

Comment: @FernandoLozano.  You are right. Skipping the validation is not the best solution but without registering the (as point 2) URL we may not proceed further.

Comment: When you write "redirect:", [RequestDataValueProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestDataValueProcessor.html) of Spring MVC is invoked, you can see it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html#createView). HDIV implements that interface so HDIV is aware of that redirect. It is no necessary to register that URL.

Comment: Thanks JayP! The second solution you suggested works and suits my requirement.